# Powershell XML count error

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

Currently I'm working on a little powershell script which process an XML file and display some statistics info from it.

At a part I'd like to count the occurence of a node and here I run into trouble.
Everything works as it should be except the fact that it do not write to the host if there is only 1 occurence.
In other cases it is ok, but when tehre is only one instance to count, the count property (or fucntion sry I'm not sure whic one is this) got no value.

Anyone experienced ever the same?
I'm new in PS it's about a few days so if I did some idiot thing sorry for that in advance :)

Here is the code snippet:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\serverdata.xml)
foreach($LogFile in $xml.Server.LogFolderRootPath.LogFolderToCheck.LogFiles.LogFile)
{
  $LogFile.SendFailedLines.SendFailedMessage.Count
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it into an array. For example:

```
(,($countme)).count
```

Comment: Well thx for the reply but here is a really basic question: How can I make the parse? I mean I should use some [string] like prefix, but it do not works as well. :S

Comment: You can use my example. just replace $countme with whatever you are trying to count :)

Comment: Well yeah I did but after that there was no result at all :))

Comment: Could you give me the part of your script where you do the count?

Comment: And replacing `$LogFile.FailedToReachMessages.FailedToReach.Count` with `(,($LogFile.FailedToReachMessages.FailedToReach)).Count` gives no results at all?